# Pushstate in pjax only when redirecting

Tags: yii2, pjax

In one of my pages I have a link that is handled by pjax. Basically the user clicks an item, this item becomes "checked" (and saved in the DB).

I have disabled pushState for these requests, because it makes no sense, user effectively stays in the same page, so it's counter-intuitive to change the url.

However, there is a case when this pjax request results in redirect to login page (when the user is not logged in). And this is when I really need pushState to work, and it doesn't because I disabled it in the first place.

Would it be possible to configure pjax in such a way that normal responses work without pushState, but redirect responses (done with `X-Pjax-Url` header) *do* perform pushState?

Comment: You can easily handle 2 different pjax config in the same page. Please add some details about how you are using pjax.

Comment: Sure, I could make two different pjax blocks, one with redirection, one without, but I need _one_ link to behave differently depending on server's reply code. Actually, I've looked at the pjax's source code and I now doubt it's possible, because it always does a replaceState if response code is 301, 302 or 303.

Comment: You don't need another pjax "block"

Comment: I know this is an old post, but you can use the `linkSelector` to define a jQuery selector to  use pjax only on specific button (I do that for state change toggles and delete buttons)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to do it using current functionality. I've added two more options to pjax and my PR has been accepted to yii2 branch of pjax. So, without further ado:

https://github.com/yiisoft/jquery-pjax

```
//pushRedirect - Whether to pushState the URL for redirects. Defaults to false.
//replaceRedirect - Whether to replaceState the URL for redirects. Defaults to true.

// ...

jQuery(document).pjax("#example_selector", {
  "push": false,
  "replace": false,
  "pushRedirect": true,
  "replaceRedirect": false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a linkSelector to specify which links trigger the pjax calls

```php
<?php Pjax::begin([
    'enablePushState' => false, // don't change the Browser URL
    'linkSelector' => 'pjax-btn', // pjax links that 
]); ?>

<?= GridView::widget([
    //...
    [ // no pjax, normal linl
        'label' => 'link with state replace',
        'format' => 'raw',
        'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
            return Html::a($model->title, Url::to(['/controllet/action', 'id' => $model->id]));
        }
    ],
    [
        'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        //'class' => 'common\widgets\ActionColumn',
        'template' => '{toggle} {view} {update} {delete}',
        'buttons' => [
            'toggle' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                $options = [
                    'title' => 'Privacy',
                    'aria-label' => 'Privacy',
                    'class' => 'pjax-btn', // no state replacement, load with pjax
                ];
                $icon = Html::tag('span', '', ['class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-check']);
                return Html::a($icon, $url, $options);
            },
        ]
    ]]) ?>
 <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```